# What does "cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type 'UITextField' " mean?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I have a string of code that is `lrs24 = (30 * Int(weight)! + 70) * Int(factor)!;`. It seems like it's all OK, but the compiler says that it "cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int'  with an argument list of type 'UITextField' ". What does this mean, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

**PS-** Here is *all* my code-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var animalNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var logLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var weight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var deh: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var losses: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var factor: [UITextField]!

@IBOutlet weak var lrs24: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    animalNum.delegate = self
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    logLabel.text = textField.text
}

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
    logLabel.text = "Default Text"
}


@IBAction func textFieldsDidEndEditing(sender: AnyObject) {
    lrs24 = (30 * Int(weight)! + 70) * Int(factor)!;
    //+ Int(weight)! * Int(deh)! * 10 + Int(losses)!



    //(30 * &weight + 70) * &factor + &weight * &deh * 10 + &losses
}

}
```

Answer (score 7):

The error is exactly what it says: **You cannot use a UITextField as the argument when initializing an Int**

Here's the code you're using in your `textFieldsDidEndEditing` function

```
lrs24 = (30 * Int(weight)! + 70) * Int(factor)!
                 ^ ^ ^ ^              ^ ^ ^ ^
                 | | | |              | | | |
         Defined as a UITextField!    | | | |
                               Defined as a [UITextField]!
```

You're trying to tell Swift to create a new integer, `Int()`. To create the integer, you're giving Swift a text field, `weight` and `factor`. Where is Swift supposed to get the integer value from? A `UITextField` is not an integer.

To put that into perspective, it's like trying to turn an apple into an orange - it's impossible to do (unless you have dark magic, but that's a different subject). The same sort of idea applies to this - you can't turn a field where a user can enter text into a number. It just doesn't work!

You *can* however turn a string, for example, into an integer because it contains data that the integer can be initialized with. For example, it's quite simple to turn the string `"7901"` into a number using `Int("7901")` because you're giving Swift data that it can turn into an integer.

If you would like to get the text that was entered in the text field, you have to use the [`UITextField.text`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/text) variable. For example, to get the number entered in the `weight` field, you could use

```
//This should only be used if you are 100% sure that the text will be a number
//If it isn't, using this code, the app will crash
var weightInteger: Int = Int(weight.text)!

//If you aren't 100% sure the input will be a number, you should use
var weightInteger: Int = Int(weight.text) ?? 0
```

You'll be able to do this because of the above `Int` initialization with a `String`

I would also assume that the `factor` variable shouldn't be a `[UITextField]!`, which is an array (or list) of `UITextFields`. Instead, it should probably be a `UITextField!` (of course, I might be wrong, and you may actually be storing a list of `UITextFields` in that variable, in which case you would have to use a `for` loop to get the values in the list.

If you want to set the *text* of a label, you have to use [`UILabel.text`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text) - you can't just set the `UILabel` to a string.

So, in the end, assuming that `factor` is supposed to be a `UITextField!` and not a `[UITextField]!`, you should use

```
let value: Int = (30 * (Int(weight.text) ?? 0) + 70) * (Int(factor.text) ?? 0)
//You may want to change the last bit
//(Int(factor.text) ?? 0) to (Int(factor.text) ?? 1)
//Which would set the factor to "1" instead of "0"
//if a non-integer or nothing is inputed

lrs24.text = "\(value)"
//this sets the text of the label to
//the value above. It has to be in the format
//"\(x)" because we have to turn x into a String.
//If you prefer, you could also use String(x)
//which would be String(value) in this example
//that's personal preference, though
```

Also, although this has nothing to do with the original question, here are some things you should do to your code to make it better

- You don't need a `;` at the end of the line - Swift automatically ends lines for you
- You should avoid forcing unwrapping (the `!` operator) unless you're ***really*** sure the value won't be nil. Instead of using `Int(x)!`, you should use `Int(x) ?? 0`, which will instead of crashing give a value of "0" if the initialized integer is `nil`.

Comment: I understand, but what way am I supposed to collect the number that the user enters into those text fields?

Comment: @George I just updated the question, which assumes that `factor` is actually supposed to be a `UITextField!` instead of a  `[UITextField]!` (I may be wrong on this, depending on what you're doing)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed your update about the `[UITextField]` thing, and I changed it. However, the compiler now says that it "Cannot assign type 'Int' to type 'String' "...

Comment: @George Yep, that's an error I made - You have to turn the value into a string before putting it into the label (as the label's text has to be a string). I updated the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just did what you said in your answer, and I had a fatal error... maybe I typed the code wrong?

Comment: @George What's the error say? If it says "Unexpectedly found nil", then you should use `?? 0` instead of `!` on the integers

Comment: It says something like "0 specialized_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString,StaticString, UInt) -> ()". I think it has to do with the zero... When I type in 25 in the Weight textfield, it freezes, and the error appears in xcode

Comment: @George Could you put the error on pastebin or something? It would be helpful if I could see the entire thing

Comment: @George Try replacing `weight.text` with `weight.text ?? "0"` and `factor.text` with `factor.text ?? "0"`